# Add "via application-name" in Facebook API post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm currently trying to increase my app visibility on shared post.

Here is what happens :

1/ Users login via facebook on my web application

2/ The login is based on a Facebook app, i added a platform "Web" in its settings

3/ I ask for basic permission + access to pages (read/write)

4/ I save some access token to the page they want to post to

5/ They are able to post some content to https://graph.facebook.com/page-id/photos or https://graph.facebook.com/page-id/feed

Well, it works, but the post doesn't show the "via Application-name" on their header. Sometimes it show : by Author-name (where author is the user who facebook logged in oO)

Thanks for the help !